# $400$ light bulbs, $16$ of them defect. Take $25$ light bulbs, what's probability that at most $2$ defect?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are in total $400$ light bulbs where exactly $16$ of them are defect. What's the probability that from $25$ light bulbs, you get at most $2$ defect light bulbs? (everything is done with replacement)

---

I think because this is with replacement and every time we take light bulb, we have specific probability so needed use binomial probability?

You have probability $p= \frac{16}{400}$ to pick defect light bulb.

But now we concentrate on $25$ light bulbs instead of $400$.. I think $p$ stay same anyway? Ok and other parameter $n$ is $25$.

Again I say, we have $p= \frac{16}{400}$ and $n=25$

Now we needs put all in binomic formula

$${n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

How put it good in formula? We have at most $2$ so we put like that?

$$P(X \leq 2) = {25\choose 0} \cdot \left(\frac{16}{400}\right)^{0} \cdot \left(0-\frac{16}{400}\right)^{25-0} + {25\choose 1} \cdot \left(\frac{16}{400}\right)^{1} \cdot \left(1-\frac{16}{400}\right)^{25-1} \approx 0.3754 \approx 37.54 \text{%}$$

Pls need know it for exam if solution is good and if not good how do it correct?

Comment: Usually probability is expressed as a decimal/fraction not a percentage.

Comment: You calculated $P(X < 2)$.  You need to add the probability of $P(X = 2)$.